# Diagonal sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Can anyone point me to a formula of generalized diagonal sums in Pascals triangle.
It is known for fixed $k$  that
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}k \\ k \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}k+1 \\ k\end{array}\right) + \cdots +\left(\begin{array}{c}n \\ k \end{array}\right) =
\left(\begin{array}{c}n+1 \\ k+1 \end{array}\right)$$
I'm looking for a generalization of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}k \\ k \end{array}\right) +\left(\begin{array}{c}k+d \\ k \end{array}\right) +\left(\begin{array}{c}k+2d \\ k \end{array}\right) +
\cdots + \left(\begin{array}{c}k+N\cdot d \\ k \end{array}\right)$$ for positive $d\in\mathbb{N}$ or possibly

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}k \\ k \end{array}\right) +\left(\begin{array}{c}2k \\ k \end{array}\right) +\left(\begin{array}{c}3k \\ k \end{array}\right) +
\cdots + \left(\begin{array}{c}(N+1)\cdot k  \\ k \end{array}\right)$$ i.e. $d=k$

Thanks

Comment: `\binom n k` yields $\binom nk$ without all the `\left(…\right)` and array stuff in your question text.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new here :-)

Comment: The generating function approach doesn’t seem much help. Let $$f(x)=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}=\frac1{(1-x)^{k+1}}$$

Then the coefficient of $x^{nD}$ of $h(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^D}f(x)$ is your sum. You might be able to get a partial fraction here. You definitely get the function is of the format: $$\frac{p(x)}{1-x^D}+\frac{q(x)}{(1-x)^{k+2}}$$ where $p,q$ are polynomials of degree at most $D,k+1$ respectively, and $p(1)=0.$ But the coefficient of $x^{nD}$ will depend on $p(0)$ and $q(x).$

Comment: The main reason the $D=1$ sums easily  is because the sum telescopes: $$\binom{n}k=\binom{n+1}{k+1}-\binom{n}{k+1}$$

Comment: As a general rule, given $k,D$ you can write $$\binom{k+Dx}{k}=\sum_{i=0}^k a_i \binom{i+x}{i}.$$ Then $$\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{k+Dj}{k}=\sum_{i=0}^k a_i\binom{n+i+1}{i+1}.$$ But figuring the $a_i$ is tedious. You easily get $a_k=D^k,$ but otherwise…

Comment: When $k=2,$ you get $$D^2\binom{3+n}3-\frac{3}2D(D-1)\binom{2+n}{n}+\frac12(D-1)(D-2)(n+1)$$